# PHP Preventing Duplicate Files code optimization

Tags: php

So i use MD5 currently to check for duplicate uploads, but i read that sha256 is better will it effect the speed i can check large files of even 2gb in size.

```
$fname = $_FILES['Filedata']['tmp_name'];
$filesource = md5(file_get_contents($fname));
```

If i was to change to sha256 would i encounter performance issues.

```
$fname = $_FILES['Filedata']['tmp_name'];
$filesource = sha256(file_get_contents($fname));
```

This is where i got my original code from http://webdevrefinery.com/forums/topic/6560-duplicate-fileimage-checking-with-php-and-md5/

Comment: Why don't you try it out yourself? Pick a few large files and record how much time it takes for both functions. Real-world data is always preferable to some SO user telling you what's best.

Comment: Don't do `md5(file_contents())`. that forces PHP to load the entire file into memory first. Large files will exhaust your memory limit and kill your script. use `md5_file()` instead.

Comment: Thanks i shall give a whirl

Comment: I am now using sha1_file(); and it seems to be pretty good regardless of size i upload would love it if php did sha256_file();

Comment: In order to check for duplicates, hashing is not a safe method because of hash collisions, as unlikely as they are. You only know that if two files have different hashes they are different, but even if they have the same hash they could still be different. In effect, that means that you must be prepared to load both files and to compare them.

Comment: Yes but the longer the hash you use the less likely you are to encounter a collision, www.virustotal.com is a brilliant example using multiple hash sums to check for duplicate files.

Comment: Using multiple (or longer) hashes is just pessimizing the general case (i.e. adding overhead) and still not even reliable. Do that if you like, I prefer solutions that don't stop short of 100% but that go the whole way.

Comment: What soloution would you have then ?